# hicolor icon error in pgadmin3, but hicolor-icon-theme installed

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS 7.0 box that I am SSHing into from Windows with putty and the Xming Windows server. When I run pgadmin3 (installed via yum) I get the following:

```
(pgadmin3:23011): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find the icon 'inode-directory'. The 'hicolor' theme
was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
You can get a copy from:
        http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases
```

However, I have all the freedesktop icons installed:

```
[zippy@localhost ~]$ sudo yum list *-icon-theme
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
 * epel: mirrors.mit.edu
 * extras: mirrors.maine.edu
 * updates: mirror.netdepot.com
Installed Packages
faience-icon-theme.noarch                                                      0.5-4.el7                                                                           @epel
gnome-colors-icon-theme.noarch                                                 5.5.1-7.el7                                                                         @epel
gnome-icon-theme.noarch                                                        3.8.2-3.el7                                                                         @base
hicolor-icon-theme.noarch                                                      0.12-7.el7                                                                          @base
mate-icon-theme.noarch                                                         1.10.1-0.1.git20150505.c6e5c6c.el7                                                  @epel
mono-icon-theme.noarch                                                         1:4.10.5-4.el7                                                                      @base
nuvola-icon-theme.noarch                                                       4.10.5-4.el7                                                                        @base
oxygen-icon-theme.noarch                                                       4.10.5-2.el7                                                                        @base
[zippy@localhost ~]$
```

How do I load the icons?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The bug exists in pgadmin, [similar to this Inkskape bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/346266), and may be related to this entry in [pgadmins git CHANGELOG](http://www.pgadmin.org/support/issues.php):

> [GTK] Crash with some themes; probably gtk issue.

I would contact someone on the [Development Team](http://www.pgadmin.org/development/team.php), and ask if the issue you're having is related to the above entry.  If not, let them know of the issue, and if you get the run around, [contact CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/Documentation?action=show&redirect=GettingHelp),and ask if a version bump is possible for `hicolor-icon-theme.noarch`, or `pgadmin`.